# Pandas DatetimeIndex truncate error

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
Out[16]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 269850 entries, 2012-12-19 16:15:36 to 2012-12-20 14:36:55
Data columns:
X1    269850  non-null values
X2      269848  non-null values
X3      269848  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
```

And I would like to slice the dataframe to return a four hour window of data from `2012-12-20 05:00:00` to `2012-12-20 09:00:00`

When I try:

```
Slicedf = df.truncate(before='12/20/2012 05:00:00',after='12/20/2012 09:00:00')
```

The following error occurs:

```
KeyError: datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 5, 0)
```

I have also tried (from [Pandas DataFrame slicing by day/hour/minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910187/pandas-dataframe-slicing-by-day-hour-minute)):

```
from datetime import datetime
x=datetime(2012,12,20,5,0,0)
y=datetime(2012,12,20,9,0,0)
Slicedf = df.ix[x:y]
```

which returns the exact same error.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: That's strange, could you update to 0.10.1? Does this also happen with `df1 = df.head()`? If so could you paste the contents of `df1.to_dict()`? (I tried with a dummy DataFrame early and it worked ok...)

Comment: Currently with 0.10.0 `df1=df.head()` works fine. Will update pandas and try again.

Comment: Sorry I meant do `df1.truncate(..)` and `df1.ix[x:y]` work fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df` was created by concatenating multiple dataframes together using the `concat` function.

`df = df.sort()` before truncation fixed the error.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to change it to:

`df = df.sort_values()` or `df = df.sort_index()` before the truncate function in order to fix the error in later versions of Pandas.

So your code would look like: `df = df.sort_index().truncate(before='12/20/2012 05:00:00', after='12/20/2012 09:00:00')`

`sort` was deprecated for DataFrames in favor of needing to use either `sort_values` or `sort_index`. You can find more details about each in the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), respectively.